# Are the fictitious names "Initech" and "Initrode" a play on words?

Tags: idioms, connotation

In the comedy film "Officespace", the protagonist works for a company called "Initech".  At the end of the film, his co-workers take jobs at a competing company called "Initrode".

It seems that these names are meant to sound silly, but can someone here tell me if these fictitious names may also be some sort of word-play?

Comment: To the more experienced users of this site: is there a better tag for this question?

Comment: Too Localised. To the limited extent that it's a "play on words", I suspect all we're dealing with is that *Initech* is a typical "high-tech" name, with *Initrode* a dorky imitation from a parvenu competitor riding on the coattails *(In it rode)*.

Comment: I'm afraid questions about naming are off topic.

Comment: ... and in an attempt at hitting a happy medium, I am going with "not constructive", because only the screenwriter(s) can tell for sure.

Comment: Worth noting: [we do have a site for questions about movies](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-space).

Comment: Yeah...  If you could just, check out the answer I received to this question on movies stack exchange... that would be greawt. http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3720/are-the-fictitious-names-initech-and-initrode-a-play-on-words/3740#3740